# *Python* Using function parameters to repeat an element of a list within a list

Tags: python, list, function

I have a question regarding list operations and function parameters within Python.

Lets say I have the function

```
def list_and_index_repeat(a,b,c)
```

Now lets say that our **a** parameter is our list

```
list_and_index_repeat([1,2,3,4],b,c)
```

and our **b** parameter is our index within the said list.

```
list_and_index_repeat([1,2,3,4],3,c)
```

where the **interger** 3 represents our third element **4**

Now that we have our element **4** how I would I repeat this element **within** that original list **a**

Example:

```
list_and_index_repeat([1,2,3,4],3,2)
```

So I am taking the **third** element within the list and then **repeating** it by 2 so I am left with the final output:

```
final_output[1,2,3,4,4,4]
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
def list_and_index_repeat(a, b, c):
    return a[:b] + [a[b], *[a[b]] * c] + a[b + 1 :]


out = list_and_index_repeat([1, 2, 3, 4], 3, 2)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use the list.extend() method to achieve this.
for example:

```
a = []
a.extend(2 * "c")
print(a)
```

It will return this
["c", "c"]

Comment: how do You plan exactly to raise 2 (an integer) to the power of "c" (a string)? even mathematically that is impossible since c is not even a variable it is a literal string

Answer (score 0):

Make a slice of the list up to b + 1 then, append the value at a[b] c times to the new list and return it:

```
def list_and_index_repeat(a,b,c):
    new_list = a[:b+1]
    
    for _ in range(c):
        new_list.append(a[b])
    
    return new_list

print(list_and_index_repeat([1,2,3,4],3,2))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4]
```